# Python Class private attribute created inside an exec function in __init__ method becomes public attribute instead of private attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to creating a class Customer which creates it's attribute from sqlalchemy query object.

```
data = {'Name':'John Doe','Age':67} #in the real code , data is a not a dictionary but an object. 

class Customer:
   
    def __init__(self,data) -> None:
        assert type(data) == Customers
        for key in data.keys():
            exec(f"self.__{key[1:] if key.startswith('_') else key} = data['{key}']",{'self':self,'data':data})
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__Name
data['bank'] = green
person = Customer(data)
```

I was able to access the  Customer attributes as a public attribute :

`print(person.__Name)`
it prints out `John Doe`

but when i try to access the attribute through the name method,
like this :
`print(person.name)`
it raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HP\PyProject\FlaskProject\green\bank\modelx.py", line 66, in name
    return self.__Name
AttributeError: 'Customer' object has no attribute '_Customer__Name'
```

How can i make the class atributes created in the exec function act as a private attribute of the class and not a public attribute.

Comment: Name mangling doesn't work when setting via `exec`, it's done at compile time and thus the `self.__...` must literally exist in the source code, not cobbled together at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You don' need `exec` here. Use `setattr`.

```
for key in data:
    setattr(self, key[1:] if key.startswith('_') else key, data[key])
```

Also, use `isinstance`, not type comparison.

```
assert isinstance(data, Customers)
```

though in your example, `data` is *not* an instance of `Customers`; it's an ordinary `dict` passed to `Customer.__init__`.

Comment: Not that this solves the fundamental problem…

Comment: True. I would simply recommend not use `__`-prefixed names in the first place, though.

Comment: I would also recommend defining `__init__` to take explicit parameters, rather than accepting an arbitrary `dict`, to avoid surprises at runtime concerning which attributes actually get defined.

Comment: Tried it , it's still the same